# how to fix the typescript download file did not popup the download window

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I am using this typescript code to download file in react application:

```
const handleDownloadPdf = async (pdfUrl: string) => {
    if (!pdfUrl) {
        toast.error("PDF url is null");
        return;
    }
    try {
        const response = await fetch(pdfUrl);
        const blob = await response.blob();
        const downloadUrl = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([blob]));
        const link = document.createElement('a');
        link.href = downloadUrl;
        link.setAttribute('download', new Date().getTime() + '.pdf');
        document.body.appendChild(link);
        link.click();
        document.body.removeChild(link);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error downloading PDF:', error);
    }
}
```

But now I found when I invoke the download function, sometimes it did not popup the download window in google chrome browser. Am I missing something? what should I do to fixed this issue? I have test the file url works fine. I have tried to debugginng this function in devtool and there is no error message output. What may cause this issue? The url may look like this `https://tex.example.top/tex/static/proj/2024/1/12c1b7d559944c47bafb756dd60d4a33/main.pdf?v=d252a45c474d44bf94de97dc144aa924`, I can open it directly in google chrome browser.

Answer (score 1):

A bit refactored your code, since everything is done in the same function I thought about splitting it to make it more functional and manageable:

```
const handleDownloadPdf = async (pdfUrl: string) => {
    if (!pdfUrl) {
        toast.error("PDF url is null");
        return;
    }
    const response = await fetch(pdfUrl);
    if (!response.ok) {
        const message = `An error has occured: ${response.status}`;
        throw new Error(message);
    }
    const blob = await response.blob();
    return blob;
}
handleDownloadPdf().then(pdfFile => {
    const downloadUrl = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([pdfFile]));
    const link = document.createElement('a');
    link.href = downloadUrl;
    link.setAttribute('download', new Date().getTime() + '.pdf');
    document.body.appendChild(link);
    link.click();
    document.body.removeChild(link);
}).catch(error => {
    error.message; // 'An error has occurred: 404'
});
```

This works for me: [Example playground](https://playcode.io/1769006)

Credits: [source](https://dmitripavlutin.com/javascript-fetch-async-await/)

[Source for the pdf used for the playground](https://www.clickdimensions.com/links/TestPDFfile.pdf)

Comment: I've updated the post with the source. I've taken the pdf as a dummy from the web but it's nothing fancy. Tried with chrome and firefox and it works, also for some friend of mine. I don't know what you're getting

Comment: @KJ you lost me. I mean, what are you saying OP is trying to achieve? From my understanding he is getting a PDF file content from a url then wrapping it into a blob and generating the url to download it. "inline not attached as a download only" is the part I don't get